# Pandas - How to sum time in a dataframe / column using pandas / numpy

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time, pivot

df with a column of time in HH:MM:SS

```
Input:
    Time
    10:00:00
    10:00:00
    10:00:00
    10:00:00
```

When i try to sum, output is

```
1 day 16:00:00
```

where as i need it like this

```
Output:
Time
40:00:00
```

Comment: Share your code that tries that

Comment: Please add code that creates a small dataframe and does the sum. The people proposing solutions shouldn't have to do that part for you.

Answer (score 0):

I created your *Series* the following way:

```
s = pd.Series([pd.Timedelta('10:00:00')] * 4)
```

so that its full printout is:

```
0   10:00:00
1   10:00:00
2   10:00:00
3   10:00:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

The problem is that *s.sum()* is by default formatted as `Timedelta('1 days 16:00:00')`, so to format it your way, write the following function:

```
def tdFormat(td):
    nn = td.seconds
    secs = int(nn % 60)
    nn = nn // 60
    mins = int(nn % 60)
    nn = nn // 60 + td.days * 24
    return f'{nn:02d}:{mins:02d}:{secs:02d}'
```

and generate the sum as:

```
tdFormat(s.sum())
```

The result is:

```
'40:00:00'
```